# Resolutions causing CSS menu issue

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

I've been trying to solve this issue for about a week though no luck.  I cannot understand what is causing the menu to change lengths at a) different resolutions and b) different zoom levels.

http://www.aplustutoring.com.au/JoomlaInstall/index.php/about

You can clearly see the menu does not equal the length of the body text which it should (if not try one level different zoom).  I've made a lot of changes the menu and I'm beginning to think that this has caused the issue.

Any ideas on what css properties I should change?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is being causes by using percentages for margins. Why these are being used I do not know. To fix this isue, open the template.css file within your template folder.

On **line 8**, change this:

```
margin: -0.2% 0 0;
```

to this

```
margin: 0;
```

And on **line 114**, change this

```
margin-top: -1.9%;
```

to this:

```
margin-top: 0;
```

---

On line 114 you can change `0` to a value that suits your needs, however please stick to using pixels as a unit of measure.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help.  However; I tried this and still the same issues.  The menu is still moving to the left/right when zooming or it has different positions at different screen resolutions.  Should I also be clearing my browser cache to review changes?

Comment: Not always necessary, but try clearing your browser cache anyway. Also try clearing the Joomla cache in the Global Configuration if you have it turned on.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I completely mis-read the question. My answer fixes the issue with the menu moving up and down according to the width of the browser

Comment: no worries, would you be able to have a look at the menu moving right?  Specifically, it appears 'fixed' to the left side, yet the right side does move slightly. Thanks again

Comment: If I am following your issue correctly, then this is the typical behavior for non-responsive elements. Are you expecting the menu width to adapt according to the width of the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove padding-left and padding-right on "rt-container", also remove all padding on "rt-containerInner" and remove margin-left. Basically there are a lot of containers and some have different values for padding left and right. I would simplify everything by removing any left-right padding and margin and adding only to individual items that need it if any.

Also the menu container is not fully filled up with the menu items hence the discrepancy.
I can help tidy this up, if you have the full .css file

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello.  Thanks for help but the issue still does exist.  Can you elaborate more on the menu container and how i might fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: In Chrome you can right click the menu item -> Inspect Element -> Select 'rt-menubar' from the elements that will appear in a new window or at the bottom of the page. So as you hover over each item you will see if it is aligned or needs tweaking and you can make changes in this as well to preview what will happen. In this view it is clear that the menu is not filling up the whole of the menu container. This should be taken into consideration.